# for each row trigger and no 'new' relation

Tags: postgresql, triggers, insert

i have 'after insert', 'for each row' trigger. on each insert it should insert a few rows to different table.

in the trigger function i can do:

```
insert into c values (
   new.column1
)
```

but when i try to change it to more powerful version (before making much more complex inserts)

```
insert into c select
   new.column1
from new
```

i get an error:

> ERROR: relation "new" does not exist

how can insert values calculated from a query that refers to values of `new`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new` in a trigger function is a composite variable representing the row being inserted, so you can just:

```
insert into c
select new.column1;
```

Answer (score 1):

the [NEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtrigger.html) keyword references the newly inserted values. To access any of the values, you don't need to `SELECT` from the table, you can simply:

```
INSERT INTO c (column1) VALUES NEW.column1
```